# Why does YAML::Load work, but relative path using require doesn't

Tags: ruby

I have a /scripts folder that contain some ruby scripts for my project.

```
/scripts
/scripts/app/models.rb
/scripts/config/config.yml
/scripts/lib
/scripts/lib/myapp/test.rb
```

In my test.rb, I have the following code which correctly loads the config.yml file:

```
env = ENV['ENV'] || 'development'
config = YAML::load(File.open('config/config.yml'))[env]
```

Now at the top of the test.rb file, I am trying to load my models.rb file which I am using with ActiveRecord, but I get an error:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../../", 'models')
```

Error:

1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- lib/myapp/../../models (LoadError)

I tried:

```
require 'app/models'
```

that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong, and why does the config.yml file load correctly?

Comment: Did you try require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../../", 'app/models')?

Comment: you mean ```__FILE__``` right? same error.

Comment: Why not use `require_relative "../../app/models"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File.open uses explicit path, but require tries to search in PATH. Ruby >= 1.9.2 does not add current directory to a search path - so you need to specify it explicitly

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "./../../app", 'models')
```

or use require_relative

```
require_relative '../../app/models'
```

Alternatively you can add current directory to search path (not recommended, this was removed from ruby for security considerations)

```
$: << '.'
```

Comment: so all these gems that are going to be ported to > 1.9.2 have to change all their require references?

Comment: Not really, this is the problem only for scripts you are running from command line